# Return last item of strings.Split() slice in Golang

Tags: go, split, slice, file-extension

I am [splitting](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) file names in Go to get at the file extension (e.g. `import ("strings") ; strings.Split("example.txt", ".")`).
For this reason, I would like to return the last item in the slice returned by the split, i.e.

> for strings.Split("ex.txt", "."), I want txt

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535775/the-last-element-of-a-slice#22535888) question suggests that doing

```
strings.Split("ex.txt", ".")[len(strings.Split("ex.txt", ".")) - 1]
```

is the only way to get at it. That is, there is no `-1` as in Python. This seems very wasteful to me, as I feel we are doing the same splitting operation twice.

- Is there no better command for getting the last item of a slice in Go?
- If no, would the best approach be to write the result of `Split` into a variable, or just do the above?

Comment: Use a variable, please.

Comment: ... another approach: `"ex.txt"[strings.LastIndex("ex.txt", ".")+1:]`, but still, please use a variable for the string because this is ugly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should assign the results of the split to a variable, instead of calling it twice.

```
ss := strings.Split(msg, ".")
s := ss[len(ss)-1]
```

(Notice that this allows (or maybe forces) you to deal with the case where `ss` is empty or something else unexpected explicitly, before indexing it.)

If you're doing this over and over again, and it offends you having to use two lines (or two lines plus error handling) instead of one, you can abstract it into a function easily:

```
func lastString(ss []string) string {
    return ss[len(ss)-1]
}

s1 := lastString(strings.Split("example.txt", "."))
s2 := lastString(strings.Split("example.jpg", "."))
```

After all, passing the result of a function as an argument has essentially the same effect as binding it to a variable.

Answer (score 58):

[`strings.LastIndex`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#LastIndex) makes this quite neat:

```
s := "Hello,Stack,Overflow"
last := s[strings.LastIndex(s, ",")+1:]
fmt.Println(last)
```

returns "Overflow". If the search string isn't found it returns the whole string, which is logical.

Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/pn9rCj3sz57)

Answer (score 7):

I would use the filepath package rather than parsing it yourself:

```
import "path/filepath"

s := "file.ext"
ext := filepath.Ext(s)
if len(ext) != 0 {
    fmt.Printf("ext = %s\n", ext[1:])
} else {
    fmt.Printf("no ext\n")
}
```

This will work with a full path as well as just a file name.

Comment: Thank you! I saw that package but wanted to do it by hand for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler is to "delete" everything up to and including the (last) dot:

```
extension := regex.MustCompile(`.*\.`).ReplaceAllString("ex.txt", "")
```